# Send object from popup.js to local html page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

New to javascript and decided to try a chrome extension. I'm trying to pass the items array into my html file but it's showing up as undefined in the html in my chrome extension. Is that possible to do from the button/popup js file to a local html file? Here's what I have:

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Testing",
  "short_name": "Testing",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "./button.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Popup.js

```
var items = {};
var type = ["1","2","3"];
type.forEach(function(type,index){
    //code to store stuff into items array
}
console.dir(items) //shows everything was stored correctly

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.action == "getData") {
        sendResponse(items);
    }
    return true;
});

chrome.tabs.create({url: './hello.html', selected:true});
```

hello.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="./pasteData.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="target">PARAGRAPH</p>
</body>
</html>
```

pasteData.js

```
function getData() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"action": "getData"}, function(data) {
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = data;
    });
};

window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        getData();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `document.querySelector('button')` will get nothing, use `document.querySelector('p')` or `document.querySelector('#target')`
2. When `hello.html` is created, `popup.html` has been closed, so when you call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send message, in fact the other end of this message channel is not opened at all. That's why you get `undefined` in the callback, you could try moving this [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) logic from `popup.js` to [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) or use something like [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead.

Comment: Instead of moving the logic over, is it be possible to pass the data from popup.js to the eventpage and then retrieve it from there with the html page?

Comment: popup.js and event page both live in the extension context, you could directly access event page variables/functions through [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage)